# asp.net web application folder with default-ish page

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to do something on an .net website: I have a default page in my root directory, works as intended.  Now I need a folder, say **~/Someone**, and another folder, **~/Somebody**.  how do I get it to accept **"www.somewhere.com/Somebody"** to go to **"www.somewhere.com/Somebody/somepage.aspx"** or **"www.somewhere.com/Someone"** to go to **"www.somewhere.com/Someone/somepage.aspx"** using **"somepage.aspx"** like a default page in the respective folder?

Answer (score 0):

Open iis (inetMgr.exe) and follow these intructions

> 1) Open IIS Manager and navigate to the level you want to manage. For information about opening IIS Manager, see Open IIS Manager (IIS 7). For information about navigating to locations in the UI, see Navigation in IIS Manager (IIS 7).
>
> 2) In Features View, double-click Default Document.
>
> 3) In the Actions pane, click Add.
>
> 4) In the Name box, type the file name that you want to add to the list of default documents and then click OK. This file name will be added to the top of the default document list.

Source: [MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771439%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)